# How to change HTTPS to HTTP in Facebook via an Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, x-facebook-platform

I want to develop an App in FB which should make HTTPS browsing impossible for fb users. Or, the app must run in HTTP without SSL. Can anyone here help me? please?

Comment: ...and the question is **WHY**?!

Comment: It would be great help if you say this. please don't concern with **WHY**

Comment: Maybe we can give you an alternative and better solution for your actual problem if you tell us WHY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you do exactly the opposite? Why? Never mind...

In PHP:

```
// Enforce http
if (substr(AppInfo::appURL(), 0, 7) != 'http://') {
    header('Location: http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: This is used in the sample code provided by Facebook / Heroku, but the other way around (in order to enforce https on production!) - try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You app inside iframe and you know what url of parent page with your app without https.

Do this js in iframe on onload or onclick

```
window.top('http://needed_url');
```